# Picking up an efficient Data model Azure Cosmos Db for many to many relationship scenario

Tags: c#, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, data-modeling, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to build an application with Azure cosmos db, the requirement is to store the list of articles against a user. In this case Article and user will be having many to many mapping.

- Create would happen via a bulk push endpoint exposed via my application which should expect an article and list of the user assigned to it, It also supports remove respective users against an article.
- I should also expose an endpoint which should provide an option to get the list of articles against a user.

To solve the above two problems
I am planning to come with a container named userArticles with schema with user/id as partition key and inserting each article as a separate document

```
{
id:guid
type:"article"
article: {
id:1
}
user: {
id: guid
}
}

{
id:guid
type:"article"
article: {
id:2
}
user: {
id: guid
}
}
```

- So I can do bulk insert one document for the each of userids passed to my bulk push endpoint.
- For fetching the list of articles as I have set partition key as user/id it is a point query which would solve my performance problems.
- I can see I can only remove document by partition key in my case as userId is the partition key which i can't use it as I need to delete that particular article alone, not sure how I can do it in Cosmos?

**Note:**
*One article can have millions of users under them
But A user might have few 100s for articles under them
I can sacrifice on the write performance but not on read performance*

Is there any way I can change the model so that both bulk insert/delete and read consume less Ru/s and achieve better performance?. Or Splitting the model would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are super hard questions to answer on here because NoSQL design requires indepth knowledge of the app itself. I'm also not sure I follow your use case here but will try with this simplistic approach. Most likely the right solution for you will be more nuanced.

First, to maintain many:many relationships you will need two containers. One for users and one for articles.

To design for performance on reads for users, depending upon how large the "many" side of the relationships are, you may be able to embed articles in an array into each user document. However you need to be careful because max document size is 2MB. Also, as articles get larger they get much more expensive to update and if the user document gets updated frequently this will be prohibitively expensive to maintain. The solution then is to reference the data and add articles as separate rows in the users container with /userId as the partition key for the articles added.

What you end up with then is a "users" container with a "/userId" partition key and a user document and multiple articles documents. You will need to disambiguate the user and the article entity from each other so you'll need the "type" property as you show above with a value of "user" or "article". To get a user and all documents you simply query for the user "Select * from c where c.userId = 'user a'". If you want just the user, add a filter for "type='user a'".

Also note, that you will want as much data as you need for the articles also stored in the users container such that you can get all the properties for articles when you query by user.

To keep the data in sync you then need to use Change Feed and monitor the articles container, then anytime an article is updated, it then queries the users container for that article id and then updates each article in place. Note, that both the query will be cross partition and can get very expensive and also you will be updating multiple instances of the same article because you need to copy it for every user. However, remember that you are doing this because you are optimizing for reads for users.

Now if you say there is a one to "millions" relationship between articles and users and you want fast queries on articles, then you will have to do the same in an articles container. Here you definitely need to add users as separate rows. But you will want to keep an eye on how large your logical partitions get. Max size is 20 GB. If you get anywhere near this or if the relationship between articles:users is unbounded then you will need a partition key with more cardinality. I can't tell you what that is, but it should either be something you will always query the articles container by, or you could also try salting the partition key value, "article1_1", "article1_2", etc.

Same thing applies on maintaining the referential integrity between users and articles. You will need to use Change Feed to monitor the users container and anytime a user is updated you will need to query the articles container for that user and update every instance of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mark-brown for your detailed answer, it gives me many insights to solve my current problem. As of now, I am planning to have user collection which will have list of articles assigned to them under them as separate documents with partition key as /userId as the read gonna be done by userid alone. Unfortunately, I can't use ChangeFeed feature because of tech challenges because of Kubernates as it doesn't support cosmosDbTrigger, Any other option I have to update data across collections?

Comment: You don't need Azure Functions to run Change Feed. Change Feed can run using any compute, including Kubernetes. If this answer above resolved your question, please mark as answered so others can benefit. Thanks.